# How to get the href value when it is in JavaScript using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

In the above HTML, I would like to get the Value `"INC3000..."`.
But if I use `get_attribute()` the value returned is None as it is rendered in JavaScript during runtime.

How can I get the value of `"href=javascript:" (INC30000004609 (New))`?

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML so the element with text as `INC30000004609` can be uniquely identified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use explicit wait for the result ready. JS rendered element cannot be obtained without waiting. Neither simple requests, nor selenium without waiting.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(element_has_text(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class, "btn")]'))    
class element_has_text(object):

    def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
        if element.text:
            return element
        else:
            return False
```